# Help - Laptop as router between wireless router and Windows 7 box

Tags: linux, networking, router, connection-sharing

I'm using a cross-over ethernet cable to connect a Desktop Windows 7 box, and a laptop running on SUSE 11.2. I want Windows to connect to the internet via the laptop's wireless interface.

**Windows 7 (eth only)**
(eth) IP: 192.168.2.101/24
GW: 192.168.2.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8

**SUSE**
eth0 IP: 192.168.2.1/24
wlan0 IP: 192.168.1.103/24
GW: 192.168.1.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

**Wireless Router**
IP: 192.168.1.1

```
#
# SUSE ROUTES
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0

#
# WINDOWS ROUTES
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1    192.168.2.101    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.2.101    276
    192.168.2.101  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.101    276
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.101    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.2.101    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.2.101    276

Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1  Default
```

Comment: Any firewall running?

Comment: can you provide the routing table of windows computer too?

Comment: All FW disabled, on all machines.

Comment: can you run cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  and post the result?

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a static route to my wireless router BACK to the 192.168.2.0/24 network via 192.168.1.103 (laptop). Now windows can browse web via lappy!

SOLVED